# How to script user input into program using read() syscall?

Tags: c, system-calls, buffering

I'm working with a couple of binaries in a Linux environment, and I'm trying to script my user input. For example, with the first program prog1.c:

```
void get_input() {

    int i;
    char buffer[32];

    i = 0;

    while (i < 3) {
        memset(buffer, 0, 32);
        printf("Enter input: ");
        fgets(buffer, 31, stdin);
        printf("Your input: %s\n", buffer);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I can either run prog1 and enter the input directly from console, or I can script the input and pipe it into the program.

Entering input directly from console:

```
# ./prog1
Enter input: Stuff1
Your input: Stuff1

Enter input: Stuff2
Your input: Stuff2

Enter input: Stuff3
Your input: Stuff3

#
```

Scripting input:

```
# perl -e 'print "Stuff1\n" . "Stuff2\n" . "Stuff3\n"' | ./prog1
Enter input: Your input: Stuff1

Enter input: Your input: Stuff2

Enter input: Your input: Stuff3

#
```

Although the formatting of the output is a little messed up, the program still displays the expected output.

My problem is with the second binary prog2.c:

```
void get_input() {

    int i;
    char buffer[32];

    i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
        memset(buffer, 0, 32);
        printf("Enter input: ");
        read(0, buffer, 31);
        printf("Your input: %s\n", buffer);
        i++;
    }
}
```

When I can enter my input directly from console:

```
# ./prog2
Stuff1
Enter input: Your input: Stuff1

Stuff2
Enter input: Your input: Stuff2

Stuff3
Enter input: Your input: Stuff3

#
```

Not only does the prompt to enter input not show up until after I enter input, but I can't even script my input:

```
# perl -e 'print "Stuff1\n" . "Stuff2\n" . "Stuff3\n"' | ./prog2
Enter input: Your input: Stuff1
Stuff2
Stuff3

Enter input: Your input:
Enter input: Your input:
#
```

I did some research on the differences between `fgets()` and `read()` and discovered:

1. `fgets()` is a C function, whereas `read()` is a system call.
2. `fgets()` reads input until the newline character or EOF is encountered, whereas newline does not have the same effect on the `read()` syscall.
3. `read()` employs some sort of buffering mechanism that `fgets()` does not.

I think points 2 and 3 are the most relevant to the issue at hand, but they don't hint to me at how to solve my problem.

The user input I need to give these programs involves non-printable hex bytes, which is why directly entering such input from console is insufficient. I also cannot modify the source code to the binaries, so there is no workaround to just use `fgets()` to collect input.

My question is if there is any way to feed input into prog2 so that I get the same behavior as prog1.

Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: the function: `fgets()` is smart enough to stop inputting bytes while there is still a 'spare' byte available for the function to place NUL ('\0') byte at the end of the input.   Therefore, the buffer length parameter should be the actual length of the buffer

Comment: The question has been totally changed.

Comment: It's been changed due to Olaf's comments above. The essential problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this issue. I still cannot interact with the binary the way I want to - scripting my input from the console - but I found a way to do it programmatically.

I'm using a Python library suite that serves as a wrapper to the `subprocess` module, but you could simply write your own:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(prog2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This will open the binary as a process, and then you can interact with it using send and receive functions from within the Python script.

I hope this helps anyone else who ever encounters a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

`read(2)` does not buffer but `fgets/printf/etc` from `<stdio.h>`do for better performance.

If you want to read lines, stick with `fgets`. But if you want to read blocks of non-printable data (i.e. binary), use `fread`. And in any case, check the return value.

Comment: When debugging, I found the following when scripting my input in gdb; this is the state of the registers after the read() call:

    EAX: 0x15
    ECX: 0xbffff60c ("Stuff1\nStuff2\nStuff3\n")

I could've guess that from the output, but it doesn't help me find the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

when reading a 'binary' file (can contain NUL bytes, etc) use 'read()' or 'fread()'

When reading a text file, use 'fgets()'

Comment: I agree, but as stated in the original question, I do not have the option to modify the source, so I must work with what I have.